# The category $\mathbf{Ban_1}$ equipped with a non-obvious functor $U_1: \mathbf{Ban_1} \to \mathbf{Set}$

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces, functors

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) says that

> For *technical reasons*, the category $\mathbf{Ban_1}$ of Banach spaces and linear contractions is often equipped not with the "obvious" forgetful functor but the functor $U_1: \mathbf{Ban_1} \to \mathbf{Set}$ which maps a Banach space to its (closed) unit ball.

The category $\mathbf{Ban_1}$, in view of the above functor, is given as an example of a concretizable category.

What are these *technical reasons*? The choice of the functor seems quite odd and non-obvious. It would be great if someone could throw some light, please!

Comment: The closed unit ball functor has the convenient property of being representable.

Comment: I'm not a functional analyst, so I'm not sure how "deep" the reasons really go, but this functor has a bunch of convenient categorical properties. It is represented by $\mathbb{R}$, so it preserves limits (which the obvious forgetful functor doesn't!). Even better, it has a left adjoint, the $\ell^1$ functor. Furthermore, it reflects isomorphisms (and more generally limits), which is to say that $\mathbb{R}$ is a "strong generator", though that terminology is ambiguous. Lastly, it preserves strong epimorphisms, which is to say $\mathbb{R}$ is "projective", though this is also ambiguous.

Comment: @Thorgott I think you can summarize all that by saying that $U_1$ is monadic.